# Postgres zero-length delimted identifier at or near ""

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

Hello I want to create simple function in Postgres database (version 12)
Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crm.now()
RETURNS timestamptz AS
""
    SELECT NOW();
"" LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

ALTER FUNCTION crm.now();
```

I got error `ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" LINE 3:""`

I am new to postgres, so please could you help me what cause this problem and how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of a function needs to be passed as a [string literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) which is specified using single quotes (`'`) in SQL. Double quotes are only for [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS);

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crm.now()
   RETURNS timestamptz AS
'
 SELECT NOW();
' 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Alternatively you can use [dollar quoted](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) string constants:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crm.now()
   RETURNS timestamptz AS
$body$
 SELECT NOW();
$body$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

---

A function returning `now()` should **never** be marked as immutable.